# Translate Magento Admin config settings to config.php settings

Tags: magento2, configuration, cookie

I want to modify a setting, which I know how to find and change in the Magento Admin, - but I want to modify it in the config.php file. Which way can i find out the configuration path / syntax within the config.php file for that specific setting?

**Example**
I want to set the cookie restriction mode to **Yes** via config.php. http://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/stores/compliance-cookie-restriction-mode.html describes how to change the setting in the Magento Admin.

It seems to be possible to get the path from /src/vendor/magento/module-cookie/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
 <default>
    <web>
        <cookie>
            <cookie_lifetime>3600</cookie_lifetime>
            <cookie_httponly>1</cookie_httponly>
            <cookie_restriction>0</cookie_restriction>
            <cookie_restriction_lifetime>31536000</cookie_restriction_lifetime>
        </cookie>
    </web>
 </default>
</config>
```

... which could translate into ...

```
'system' => 
  array (
    'default' => 
      array ( 
        'web' =>
           array (
             'cookie' =>
                array (
                  'cookie_lifetime' => '3600',
                  'cookie_restriction' => '1'
```

... but that seems a bit complicated to me for everyday usage (1. find the right module, 2. investigate source code, 3. translate xml to config.php format). Is there an easier way?

Comment: Have you checked this with config:dump command?

Comment: I'm a bit worried about destroying my config with that one, @Ramkishan...

Comment: It actually was a great hint! - I took a backup of env.php and config.php first, then run `bin/magento app:config:dump`. The script updated env.php and config.php for me; I stored the two updated files in a safe place and restored the backup, so that the environment would run the same way as before. I then was able to find and copy the configurations I needed in the stored config.php file. Thank you, @Ramkishan!

Comment: your most welcome man

Comment: @Ramkishan, do you want to add it as an answer, so that I can mark it as "correct"?

Comment: Sure @where I'll do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `app:config:dump` command. This will generate system specific, configuration specific, sensitive configuration settings in `config.php` and `env.php` files. Then using `app:config:import` command you can update your configuration once you update these files.

I hope it'll work for you.