# Syntax for overriding config.xml module configuration with config.php in magento2?

Tags: magento2, module, xml, configuration

I have a module MyCompany_ExampleModule. Its `etc/config.xml` file:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <mycompany_em>
            <general>
                <enabled>0</enabled>
                <endpoint><![CDATA[https://myendpoint.example.org/test.json]]></endpoint>
                <limit>5</limit>
            </general>
        </mycompany_em>
    </default>
</config>
```

I also can see, that my colleagues read the configuration from the xml:

```
$moduleEnabled = $this->config->getValue(Config::XML_PATH_MYCOMPANY_EM_ENABLED, $store);
```

Try and error tought me how to modify the value this section in `config.php` / website scope:

```
'mycompany_em' => [
    'general' => [
        'enabled' => '1',
    ]
]
```

Why then is there an additional `PATH` in the next one?

```
$accountId = $this->config->getValue(Config::XML_PATH_MYCOMPANY_PX_PATH_ACCOUNT_ID, $store);
```

I found out that it can be modified with this section in `config.php` / website scope:

```
'mycompany_em' => [
    'general' => [
        'enabled' => '1',
        'account_id' => '1234'
    ]
]
```

But why? Is PATH a keyword? - I had created a similar question before: [Translate Magento Admin config settings to config.php settings](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/220281/translate-magento-admin-config-settings-to-config-php-settings) - but it still confuses me.